# Python refer each JSON element in an array

Tags: arrays, json

I have an array of JSON objects as follows. How do I parse each JSON object from the array?

For example, I want to parse `{"occurrences":"1","post_title":"Test 5","ID":"16"}` and send it as body to an API.

```
  [
  {
    "occurrences": "1",
    "post_title": "Test 5",
    "ID": "16"
  },
  {
    "occurrences": "1",
    "post_title": "Test 6",
    "ID": "19"
  },
  {
    "occurrences": "1",
    "post_title": "xyz,abc",
    "ID": "21"
  }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your effort in doing above ask, and what error you are facing in doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Add your searched parameters in `to_be_searched` variable.
if condition checks with all objects one by one.

```
import json

result = '[{"occurrences":"1","post_title":"Test 5","ID":"16"},{"occurrences":"1","post_title":"Test 6","ID":"19"},{"occurrences":"1","post_title":"xyz,abc","ID":"21"}]'

to_be_searched = {"occurrences": "1", "post_title": "Test 5", "ID": "16"}
result_arr = json.loads(result)

for res in result_arr:
    if res["occurrences"] == to_be_searched["occurrences"] and res["post_title"] == to_be_searched["post_title"] and \
            res["ID"] == to_be_searched["ID"]:
        print(res)
```

You can use simplejson modules as well, if you face any issue while executing above code like `AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'loads'`

Install simplejson module by executing following command on terminal
`pip install simplejson`
for python3
`pip3 install simplejson`

just change 1st line in above code to
`import simplejson as json`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. One more question, how do I quickly iterate each JSON block in an array and send it as a body to an API? {
    "occurrences": "1",
    "post_title": "Test 5",
    "ID": "16"
  }